# Create VirtualHosts for zeroconf http services

Tags: apache-2.2, http, bonjour

I have multiple `node.js` apps running on my computer, and things are getting pretty confusing since the only difference between accessing them is the port number.

So I had the idea to use [zeroconf](https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns) to advertise them. I can now see my different apps in zeroconf capable browsers (Safari).

This is a great start, but not everybody on my team can use Safari, and so I'd like them to be accessible without port number.

So I'm looking for a way, to create redirects, or VirtualHost configs, based on zeroconf services.
For example: if I have a zeroconf service called `fileserver` on machine `some-server.local:3377`, I'd like it to be accessible through `http://fileserver.services.local`, without port number.

Ideally it wouldn't redirect to `http://some-server.local:3377`, that's why I was thinking about VirtualHosts.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with zeroconf, but as I understand it, you don't have a config file as such - instead, each service will advertise itself. If this is correct, then I have a couple of suggestions.

The first is to use `mod_rewrite` and a `RewriteMap`. The `RewriteMap` will be a program that looks for the correct record and returns the informaton. Here's an example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap zeroconf:/path/to/program
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://${zeroconf:$HTTP_HOST}/$1 [P,L]
```

The program you're running as `/path/to/program` must take a hostname as argument (e.g. `fileserver.services.local`)  and return the servername and port as `some-server.local:3377`. Mod_rewrite will then proxy that connection through to that server and port - if you don't want it proxied, remove the `P` from the RewriteRule.

Another way would be to use a `RewriteMap` that consists of a regular text file, and have a cron job running to discover any change in services and update that textfile every X minutes.

Writing the program to map hostname to hostname:port is left as an exercise to the reader...